# debugging ruby with eclipse dltk

Tags: ruby, eclipse, debugging, dltk

I'm trying to debug ruby scripts with eclipse helios (dltk installed) on a win7 x64 machine and ruby1.92 environment

I installed ruby-debug19, ruby-debug-base19, ruby-debug-ide19 gems but still can't debug rb scripts with eclipse dlt it says following,

> Debugging Engine not started
>   The 'Fast Ruby Debugger (ruby-debug)' is selected, but the 'ruby-debug' gem doesn't seem to be installed in the selected Ruby Interpreter (C:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe)

I also added c:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems folder to system library paths of ruby interpreter settings in eclipse.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` environment variables on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

It's just what I've been told by my programming-prof., but he told me there is acutally no way to use the debugger for Ruby > 1.8. So, maybe, if Ruby 1.8 suits for your requirements, you could use the 1.8 interpreter for debugging.